# How do I pass down a string to message via sendemail in python

Tags: python

I am new to python.
Here' s what I have

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = "email1"
msg['To'] = "email2"
msg['Subject'] = "Item Found!"
password = "pw"

body = "<a href = ""www.ebay.ca"">Item found!</a>"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(msg['From'], password)
print("Login success")

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

## I have a list that is

```
url1 = "www.ebay.ca"
url2 = "www.amazon.ca"
list = [url1, url2]
i = 0
```

## I want to exchange

```
 body = "<a href = ""www.ebay.ca"">Item found!</a>"
```

## with

```
 body = "<a href = list[i]>Item found!</a>"
```

what's the correct way of doing this cuz I want to do a loop and have i as a dynamic variable and output the url within a message as a url, thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add strings with `+`.

```
tmp = 'str2'
str = 'str1' + tmp + 'str3'
str
>>> 'str1str2str3'
```

Therefore just write

```
body = "<a href = "+ list[i] + ">Item found!</a>"
```

Or, since python 3.6, you can use f-strings.

```
body = f"<a href = {list[i]}>Item found!</a>"
```

Full code would look like:

```
urls = [url1, url2]
for url in urls:
    body = body = f"<a href = {url}>Item found!</a>"
    # do sth with body
```

Comment: thank you, much appreciated. This will help me understand the syntax more.